# fetch values in listbox from two table using joins

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

```
User Table - 

column name - location_id

values =     4,5

Location table

column name - id , location_name

values =      4    nagpur
              5,   Akola
```

i want to display location names in listbox by joining location_id of user table,

Suppose in location_id column of user table 4,5 values are present then in my select box this only displays nagpur, Akola from location table.

i cannot understand how to explode values of location_id table before select and display only those values which are available in location_id column from location table.

```
public function getUserLocations() {  
        $this->loadModel('User');  
        $getlocations = $this->User->find('list', array(         
        'fields' => array('Location.id','Location.location_name'),
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'locations',
                    'alias' => 'Location',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array('FIND_IN_SET(User.location_id,Location.id)') 
                )                
            ),            
        )); 
        $this->set('getlocations', $getlocations);
    }
```

below is my code ..

Comment: in array, is table = locations or location ? last s in locations...

Comment: in array the values coming in locations

Answer (score 0):

Explode the variable like this :

```
$getlocations = $this->User->find('list', array(         
        'fields' => array('Location.id'));

 $location_ids[] = explode (',', $getlocations);
```

Now you will get the data in array format. Modify it according to your needs